# Sometimes, SSH stop to listen on port 22 on my dedicated server

Tags: ssh

I don't know why but sometimes, on my server, i can't connect to my server with ssh on the port 22. So, in the sshd_config file, i add the line "Port 2233" after the line "port 22" which make me able to connect on this port even when the 22 doesn't answer.

Thus i'd like to know why sometimes, ssh on port 22 doesn't work, and after a while, without intervention, it's back

Thank you all.

Comment: That is certainly very unusual. I think it could be a firewall issue, especially a fail2ban script or other ratelimiting in iptables.

Comment: well here is my iptable http://pastebin.com/Rdke49p6

Comment: You are providing too little information to tell. Are there any intervening firewalls or proxies? What does `ssh -v -v -v` tell you when it fails? Does logs on the server mention anything? Did you try `tcptraceroute` to the port; where does report failure? Is the failure intermittent from a particular client, or it works from some client and not another?

Comment: well for the moment it works, i come back with all the informations needed as soon as this behave happens again. But i did remember that a telnet on 22 doesn't answer at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have rate-limiting active in your iptables. I didn't analyze them, but if you retry without those rules, it will probably work.

Like this, only 10 connections in 5 minutes:

`REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 300 hit_count: 10 name: DEFAULT side: source reject-with icmp-port-unreachable`